# Search trough class for attribute value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, class, attributes

I got a few elements in a class that I move around.

```
<div id="bno0" class="block" style="left: 50px; bottom: 50px;"></div>
<div id="bno1" class="block" style="left: 250px; bottom: 150px;"></div>
<div id="bno2" class="block" style="left: 450px; bottom: 250px;"></div>

$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow"); 
});
```

I want to know as soon as one of them gets attributed "left:400px;"

I can detect it with:

```
if($("#bno2").css("left")=='400px')
```

But I would like a more generic functionality, is it possible?

Comment: Define "generic". Do you want to test it against all elements with that class?

Comment: Why not add the code into the click event handler? So move it 50px and then do a quick check to see if the new value exceeds 400.

Comment: Try the very little resize.js plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/ - it works very well

Comment: why can't you use [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get left value of a element

Answer (score 1):

Check this

[FIDDLE  //](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3z3Th/1/)

I am calculating the left in the callback of the animation function.. Hope it fits your requirement

```
$("#right").click(function() {

    $(".block").each(function(i) {
        var $elem = $(this)
        $(this).animate({
            "left": "+=50px"
        }, "slow", function() {
            if( parseInt($elem.css('left')) === 300){
                alert('Div with id : '+ $elem.attr('id') + ' left is 300 !!');
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

just try with this for all

```
if($(".block").css("left")=='400px')
```